# Bookmarklet - Multiple lines of input

Tags: bookmarklet

I am trying to create a simple bookmarklet that creates a little textbox that can be created, written in, and then closed.

Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

See a [live example here](https://www.taosdev.com/bookmarklet-devkit/#EQChEoAIF4D5IN4B0B2l2QMYHsUGcAXSAExhO0wFcBbAUxQIDpMAnWgQwNoFEAbWugxAByYgEsAbsPCoMJRoQCe-MkmAAHbHjEExuAFwAzMQA9axANwFs6-QAZ1Ji-0MF7ji+vbFxKAOb6AKweAEbsmADWfizYlCjEALQ4vNgs+myWarIYOPhEtGTEFDT0TKwcXHwCpSJcJgTsbOzS2ei5hJAhhcWCZU2V-L0iIZQE1igtaBghjGIoKLQsACq09arAAMIpeLRZU+gzuJi8YpFkEDDwyPty5FS9jCHYxIqMbNTYErQbABZivMQQMQZDcAL6teTsdTqejEX7-QG0EFyYiMKEw+LwgEgELIjBFe6lR7PV7o2FYwHA1Cg8AQCzAIA)

```
(() => {
    const d = document.createElement('div')
    d.style = "position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;padding:5px;background-color:red;"
    const e = document.createElement('textarea')
    const b = document.createElement('button')
    b.innerText = "Close"
    b.onclick = () => {
        document.body.removeChild(d)
    }
    d.appendChild(e)
    d.appendChild(b)
    document.body.appendChild(d)
})();
```